# Unreachable code within Cond recursive function -- why?

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

With my recursive function, I have a cond with a fail conditon.

When the concequence of the fail condition is `nil`, everything works fine.

But when I try to change the concequence of the fail condition to something else:

```lisp
(defun rec ()
  (cond ((null t) (format t ....))
        ....)
```

it says that the `(format t....)` function is unreachable... why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Common Lisp, `t` is a boolean constant that means “true”. So, the expression `(null t)` checks if `t` is the empty list and this is obviously always false. So the compiler is smart enough to infer that the code `(format ...` is never reached and does not compile it.

Errors like this arise sometimes when one forgets the meaning of `t`, and tries to use it as a variable.

Comment: That you. I also realised that instead of using `t` I should have used the list in the recusion.